# Binomial hypothesis test for $p_1 = p_2 = P$ without normal approximation

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, binomial-distribution

I was testing whether the proportion of successes from two populations is the same. It made me realize I only know how to do this with a normal approximation.

In particular, I would like to solve Exercise 9.3 from [this set of exercises](https://github.com/ArturoSbr/Principles-of-Statistics-MG-Bulmer-1965/blob/main/9_tests_of_significance.ipynb) using a binomial distribution.

I understand that you may not feel like checking out my GitHub, so here's my problem in more general terms: suppose I flip a coin 100 times to test the hypothesis that the coin is unbiased. Instead of comparing the observed number of successes against the expected number of successes under $H_0$, I want to compare the observed **proportion** of successes against the expected **proportion** of successes. How can I test this without a normal approximation?

I found [a post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/471014/is-there-any-hypothesis-test-for-two-binomial-distribution-without-normal-approx) that suggests using Fisher's exact test. This is helpful in that it skips the normal approximation, but can this be done using a binomial test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $x = 705$ successes in $n = 929$ failures, and you want to test $H_0: p = 3/4$ against $H_a: p \ne 3/4,$ at the 5% level. If $H_0$ is true, you expect about $627$ successes in $929$ trials. You will reject $H_0$ if the number $x$ of observed
successes is far from $627$ in either direction.

Under $H_0,$ you have $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n =929, p=3/4).$ For a test at about
the 5% level, you seek critical values $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that
$P(X \le c_1\,|\, H_0) + P(X \ge c_2 \,|\, H_0) \approx 0.05.$

From R, where `pbinom` is a binomial CDF and `qbinom` is a binomial quantile function (inverse CDF), we have $P(X \le 670\, |\,H_0) = 0.0243$ and
$P(X \ge 723\, |\,H_0) = 0.0244,$ so $c_1 = 670, c_2 = 723$ are suitable critical values.

```
qbinom(c(.025,.975), 929, 3/4)
[1] 671 722
pbinom(670, 929, 3/4)
[1] 0.02433703
1 - pbinom(722, 929, 3/4)
[1] 0.02441926
```

Therefore, if we observe $x = 705$ successes, with $c_1 = 670 < 705 < 723 = c_2,$
we do not reject $H_0.$

[image]

```
x = 625:775;  PDF = dbinom(x, 929, 3/4)
hdr = "PDF of BINOM(929, 3/4) with Normal Approx."
plot(x, PDF, type = "h", col="blue", main=hdr)
 abline(h=0, col="green2")
 abline(v=c(670.5, 721.5), col="red")
  mu = 929*.75;  sg = sqrt(929*.75*.25)
  curve(dnorm(x, mu, sg), add=T, lwd=2)
```

The approximating normal distribution to $\mathsf{Binom}(n=929,p=3/4)$ is
$\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=696.75, \sigma=13.20);$ it provides a very close fit.
With an approximate normal test, we would have used $c_1=670,c_2=723.$
which are not substantially different from the critical values of the
exact normal test.

```
qnorm(c(.025,.975), mu, sg)
[1] 670.8824 722.6176
```

Comment: This is super helpful. Thank you for the visualization. However, is it possible to solve 9.3 with this methodology? This is the bit where I'm currently stuck at and had to resolve to using a normal approximation.

Comment: Please state the exact problem you are trying to solve instead of relying on interpretation of one problem among several related ones in a link. // An exact test of a _difference_ of success probabilities e.g., (form men vs. women) may use Fisher's exact test and hence the hypergeometric distribution instead of binomial.